# Ubuntu 15.04. fills up root partition automatically quite quickly!

Tags: partitioning, root

I have got a funny but bad problem. The root partition is filling up quickly and automatically. I can see that there is a continous read and write process on this partion. But I cannot stop it.

It is that worse, so I have to move large amount of data from the root partition to another partition. Is this a virus? I have barley any network traffic, which makes me think that this is no virus/trojan horse or something else.

I get the message regularly that there are 0 bytes free on the root partition.

I did sudo apt-get clean and autoclean commands often and delete temporary files I do not need. Swap partition is 247 MB and it is steadly growing.

I used df -h command several times and can that root partition is getting full of data, wich data is copying there from where?

I had to do some partitioning work with gparted, did I do anything wrong?

I have never faced such a problem before.

Comment: How big is your /root partition? And why did you make it separate?

Comment: Look into /`var/log` for possible big log file, caused by a possible rogue process.

Comment: Day two! Root partition is doing some read and write process again. I have inserted a sreenshot of the filesystem. http://paste.ubuntu.com/11245857/ Root partition is running out of space again. Unstoppable!!!  I have deleted all logfiles no proper reaction. Is it malware? I am doing a malwarescan again.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem too.
And I also identified where all the disk space is going:
du -hs /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
152G    /var/lib/apt/lists/partial

It seems that there is a bug in apt: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1445239

And, the fix for it is manually installing apt 1.0.9.10 from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/1.0.9.10ubuntu1/+build/7460103

Just install apt and libapt-pkg4.12

Answer (score 0):

Install Baobab a.k.a. Disk Space Analyzer and drill down to find where the files are created. Most likely it's some process creating tons of files or continuously writing to a temp file